# error Selecting data from mysql table with php

Tags: php, mysql

pls am trying to select data from user table and i keep getting this -> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'array' (T_ARRAY) in C:\xampp\htdocs\login\selt.php on line 10

```
$conn = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "logintest");

 if (!$conn) {
die("connection aborted: ".mysqli_connect_error()); }
$run = mysql_query("Select * from user") ;
while($row=mysql_fetch array($run))
```

..Thanks

Comment: Can you identify which of those is line 10?  Also, you appear to be using the old mysql_XXX functions where I suspect you intended to use the mysqli_XXX functions...

Comment: The fetch array line is line 10..Thanks

Comment: It's just a typo: `mysql_fetch array` instead of `mysql_fetch_array`. And even that would be yet another typo: `mysql_` instead of `mysqli_` (just like you have `mysql_query` instead of `mysqli_query`).

Answer (score 0):

If you have already `mysqli_connect` before, I think you have to use `mysqli_*` functions.

And You have to use in this way.

```
$run = mysqli_query($conn,"Select * from user");

$row = mysqli_fetch_array($run, MYSQLI_BOTH);
...
mysqli_free_result($run);
mysqli_close($conn);
```

Reference this page: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-array.php

Comment: Still getting d same error..

Comment: @Specter, Please check my answer...

Comment: Thank you all..Problem solved..

Answer (score 0):

The error is coming from the space in the middle of `mysql_fetch array` (should be `mysql_fetch_array`) but as I mentioned up there (and so did @Star_Man) you should also watch out for mixing mysqli and mysql functions.